# Printing macro fails to concatenate

Tags: c++, macros

I want to create a macro that prints some info and takes any number of arguments to print additional message(s) if needed.

Here's a code snippet im talking about:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print(msg, ...) \
    printf("Line: %d File %s "## msg, __LINE__ , __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__);

int main()
{
    print("Msg: %d", 13);
    print("Msg: %d, Msg2: %d", 123, 234);
}
```

Here's an error I'm getting:

```
main.cpp:12:9: error: pasting ""Line: %d File %s "" and ""Msg: %d"" does not give a valid preprocessing token
  printf("Line: %d File %s "## msg, __LINE__ , __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you writing C code and pretending it's C++?

Comment: @paxdiablo the name of the file is main.cpp, so I think it is C style C++ code.

Comment: @mch: yes, hence the "pretend" clause in my comment :-) C-style C++ code, as you eloquently put it, is possibly the *worst* thing you can do to learn C++. Having said that, the fact that it is `main.cpp` *does* indicate C++, so I'll restore the C++ tag (and take away the C one) - it's very rare that a question should have both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C string literals are joined automatically.  The `##` you have now is meant to join two "tokens" (not strings) into one, e.g. to take `ABC` and `XYZ` and make `ABCXYZ` as an identifier.

You want this:

```
printf("Line: %d File %s " msg, __LINE__ , __FILE__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what it says on the tin: `"Line: %d File %s ""Msg: %d"` is not a single, valid preprocessing token as `##` is required to produce.

Just drop the `##`, as adjacent string literals are already concatenated by the preprocessor.